# The type of UnspecifiedBoolType? about typedef, member function pointer and conversion operator

Tags: c++, typedef

I am trying to understand the code below. What is the actual type of `UnspecifiedBoolType`?

I'm confused. Can anyone explain it to me? Thanks in advance!

```
template <typename T>
class MyOptional
{
public:    
    MyOptional() : valueIsSet(false) {}
    MyOptional(const T& value) : valueIsSet(true), value(value) {}

    // Conversion to bool. This is a variant of the "safe bool idiom".
    typedef T MyOptional<T>::*UnspecifiedBoolType;
    inline operator UnspecifiedBoolType() const;

    ...

private:
    bool valueIsSet;
    T value;
};

...

template<typename T>
MyOptional<T>::operator MyOptional<T>::UnspecifiedBoolType() const
{
    return valueIsSet ? &MyOptional<T>::value : 0;
}
```

Comment: The actual type of `UnspecifiedBoolType` is `T MyOptional<T>::*`. Can't you see the `typedef`?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I suspect that "actual type" may be an inaccurate English translation.

Answer (score 5):

As the comments in your code say, this is the "[safe bool idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Safe_bool)."  The "unspecified bool type" is a type which can be used in conditional expressions like this:

```
MyOptional<int> myop;
// ...
if (myop) {
    // ...
}
```

The reason people do this in C++ is to prevent accidental conversions from `bool` to other types via the conversion operator of a class.  For example, without the safe bool idiom you could do this:

```
MyOptional<int> myop;
// ...
int bad = myop; // bad is now zero or one, not the "value" of myop
```

Finally, note that in C++11 we no longer need obscure code like this, because now we have a language feature that lets us write this:

```
explicit operator bool();
```

Comment: This is pretty much superseded by `explicit operator bool()`s in C++11, though.

Comment: @T.C.: indeed, thanks for mentioning that, I've added it to my answer.

Comment: So this code is out of date and can be replaced by a simple explicit operator bool()? That's helpful.

Comment: @陈昱安: yes, if you are using C++11.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef T MyOptional<T>::*UnspecifiedBoolType;
```

defines `UnspecifiedBoolType` to be a pointer to member variable of `MyOptional<T>` whose type is `T`.